# Text flashing in GVim as I type (Windows)

Tags: windows, vim

This isn't really a big issue, but annoying nonetheless; when I'm typing in GVim on my Windows box, the word I'm editing will sometimes flash as I type.

This does not happen for Vim sessions in Putty, and I've never noticed this behaviour when running GVim in Linux, but I've seen it on several other Windows setups.

I'm thinking the problem is GVim won't render the word until it has figured out what syntax highlighting to use, because the flashing disappears if I disable highlighting. But not using syntax highlighting is not something I would consider a solution ;)

Has anyone else experienced the same problem? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What's the value of [`'visualbell'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'visualbell')? Use `:verbose set visualbell?` to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem actually. Copy out all the items in ~_vimrc and put them in ~_gvimrc, this should work. Not sure why though.

Comment: I tried it, but I still get the flashing problem; it seems some source files are worse than others, with LaTeX files being the worst offenders.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Change your colorscheme.

If that doesn't work try the command line, open up command prompt and type `vim` then see if you have the same problem